# Name checkboxes in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, binding

I have a `ListView` control that contains one column with checkboxes only. Is it possible to give those checkboxes some names (indexes - like 1, 2, 3...)?

I need it because I want to identify a concrete checkbox in `ToggleButton_OnCheckedUnchecked` event in some way.

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}" IsThreeState="False"
                  Checked="ToggleButton_OnCheckedUnchecked"
                  Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnCheckedUnchecked"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: You want to give names `dynamically`?

Comment: Why you need the checkbox while you have the Value bindded. do work around with Value to follow MVVM. if you are so. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it that way. Instead, have each line in your ListView have an IsChecked property, and change the IsChecked Binding to TwoWay. That way, you don't need to use the Checked and UnChecked events at all.

```
public class LineViewModel
{
   public bool IsChecked
   {
     get { return _isChecked;
   }
   set
   {
   // do something here
   }
}

<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" IsThreeState="False"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

For best results, implement INotifyPropertyChanged too.

Comment: Too much programming... I'm ashamed for myself:D Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Probably dynamic binding some names can be done through the `Binding`, like that:

```
<CheckBox Name="{Binding IdCheckBox}" ... />
```

Quote from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.name.aspx):

> Data binding a Name is technically possible, but is an extremely uncommon scenario because a data-bound Name cannot serve the main intended purpose of the property: to provide an identifier connection point for code-behind.

In short, the `Binding` Name property for control is impossible and undesirable. But you can use the attached dependency property, like this:

```
<CheckBox local:GiveName.Name="{Binding Template_Name1}" ... />
```

In any case, this is not the solution to your problems.